# UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been having a problem with UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification. I have tried using `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeChanged:) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];`
 in viewDidLoad to be notified when a new day has started. The problem is it doesn't seem to call the `timeChanged:` method when I put a breakpoint in the method. I have tested running on both on a device and in the iOS simulator by changing the date and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem now. I am running the code in swift from AppDelegate. So I am looking forward to an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work. My problem is that I was testing on the `Xcode simulator` and I was changing the time on the laptop to trigger a day change. But the time of the simulator wasn't changed.
So I had to do the same thing running on the physical device and change time over there.

Here is the code I was using inside `AppDelegate` (swift):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // day change notification
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dayChanged:", name: UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification, object: nil)

    return true
}


@objc func dayChanged(notification: NSNotification){

    print("notification received")
}
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped! When I change the date when the app is open it works but when my app isn't open it doesn't acknowledge UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification that the date has changed when I re-open the app. I'm trying to use a notification in a background refresh to see if that does the trick.

Comment: Maybe inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate(called when opening the app) add some code to test if the day changed and if yes call your code from your UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification handler.